# Dictionary containing array float32 element

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, numpy

I have two empty lists that take appended values later in my code; this is done in Python 3.5:

```
times = []
amounts = []
```

After taking on the values the lists are as follows:

```
times = [1, 2, 3, 4]
amounts = [12.34, 12.43, 87.65, 98.01]
```

I have combined these two lists into one dictionary:

```
data = dict(zip(times, amounts))
```

I need to serialize this dictionary for output as a JSON file, but I keep getting this weird output when I print the dictionary:

```
{1: array([[12.34]], dtype=float32), 2: array([[12.43]], dtype=float32)}
```

I cant create a JSON file with the float dtype still in the dict. Anyone have any ideas about how to convert the float32 to the string value needed for JSON?

When I use json.dumps I get the following:

```
array([[12.34]], dtype=float32) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? In Python 3.6.5, with `print(data)` I get the output `{1: 12.34, 2: 12.43, 3: 87.65, 4: 98.01}`

Comment: `print(data)` for me shows `{1: 12.34, 2: 12.43, 3: 87.65, 4: 98.01}`. What version of python? **Edit**: Can't reproduce this in 2.7 or 3.6

Comment: It seems to me you have mixed code from `numpy` too.

Comment: Post updated with more info

Comment: Can you explain where the `dtype=float32` comes from? How are you using `numpy`?

Comment: @pault the elements for the amounts list come from tensorflow as array elements.

Comment: Convert them to lists first, try `dict(zip(times, amounts.tolist()))`

Comment: I found the solution if anyone needs it. I had to convert the TF array type first, then flatten it, then extract the element I needed. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `times` and `amounts` that you show us, I have no problem doing a `dumps`:

```
In [140]: times
Out[140]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [141]: amounts
Out[141]: [12.34, 12.43, 87.65, 98.01]
In [142]: dd = dict(zip(times, amounts))
In [143]: dd
Out[143]: {1: 12.34, 2: 12.43, 3: 87.65, 4: 98.01}
In [144]: json.dumps(dd)
Out[144]: '{"1": 12.34, "2": 12.43, "3": 87.65, "4": 98.01}'
```

But the dictionary does not print as you show.  To get that I have to turn `amounts` into an array.

```
In [147]: arr = np.array(amounts,'float32')[:,None,None]
In [148]: arr.shape
Out[148]: (4, 1, 1)
In [149]: arr
Out[149]: 
array([[[12.34]],

       [[12.43]],

       [[87.65]],

       [[98.01]]], dtype=float32)
In [150]: dd = dict(zip(times, arr))
In [151]: print(dd)
{1: array([[12.34]], dtype=float32), 2: array([[12.43]], dtype=float32), 3: array([[87.65]], dtype=float32), 4: array([[98.01]], dtype=float32)}
```

This is not serializable - no `ndarray` is (without extra code)

```
In [152]: json.dumps(dd)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable
```